# How does the current pass in electrical circuits?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

How to find the potential difference (voltage) along the R2 and R3 resistance. (I think R3 is 0 because the current is not passing.)

How I can find the load on the capacitor C?
[image: electrical_cirsuit]

Comment: Why do you think that current isn't passing through R3? Think again.

Comment: How should the current pass on R3? I would be glad if you share your comment. @B.Anshuman

Comment: Before reaching steady state of the circuit, the charge on the capacitor must increase as it is indeed across some potential difference (assume V, which you can find by Kirchoff laws). As charge is increasing on the capacitor, dQ/dt is not 0. So current isnt zero. Remember, the circuit hasnt reached steady state yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you define 3 currents $i_1,i_2,i_3$ as in the picture below :
[image]

You’re right, at steady state, capacitor acts as an open switch, hence $i_3=0$, voltage across R$_3=0$ Volts.
Then you can write the equations for loop 1 and loop 2:
Loop 1:
$-\varepsilon +2 i_1 R_1+\left(i_1+i_2\right) R_2=0$ ... (1)
Loop 2:
$-\varepsilon +\left(i_1+i_2\right) R_2+i_2 R_1=0$ ... (2)
Solving equations (1) and (2), you can find $i_1$ and $i_2$.
Then voltage across $R_2$ is $\left(i_1+i_2\right) R_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! How I can find the load on the capacitor C

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the "load". If it's a kind of "resistance", than usually it needs alternating current to calculate it.